# OpenGL layered rendering interferes with layer 0

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, glsl, geometry-shader

I am using `gl_Layer = gl_InvocationID;` in a geometry shader to render into a framebuffer with a 3D texture attached.

This mostly works fine. Except every invocation of the shader also renders into layer 0, as well as the layer that I specify.

How can I avoid this? Is there something vital I'm missing with setting up the framebuffer? Perhaps with `glFramebufferTexture`?

### Geometry Shader

```
#version 400

layout(invocations = 32) in;
layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 raster_color;

float blue;

void main()
{
  gl_Layer = gl_InvocationID;
  blue = float(gl_InvocationID) / 31.0;

  gl_Position  = vec4( -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  raster_color = vec3( 0.0, 0.0, blue );
  EmitVertex();

  gl_Position  = vec4( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  raster_color = vec3( 1.0, 0.0, blue );
  EmitVertex();

  gl_Position  = vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  raster_color = vec3( 1.0, 1.0, blue );
  EmitVertex();

  EndPrimitive();
}
```

### Fragment Shader

```
#version 400

in vec3 raster_color;
out vec4 fragment_color;

void main()
{
  fragment_color = vec4( raster_color, 1.0 );
}
```

Comment: Can you include the geometry shader in question? I'm inclined to believe that _it_ is to blame for this, rather than your FBO setup or fragment shader (though, if you could include the fs as well, that'd help).

Comment: Sure, @Andon. I've added them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was not a problem with `gl_Layer`. It was simply a syntax error in `glTexParameter` that was causing my resulting 3D texture to repeat rather than clamp to edges.

Answer (score 4):

`EmitVertex` invalidates all per-vertex ***outputs*** after it returns. The most obvious per-vertex outputs in this shader are:

1. `raster_color`
2. `gl_Position`

But, you may not have realized that `gl_Layer` is also per-vertex or which vertex this needs to be set for.

---

`gl_Layer` will be undefined for every vertex after the first in this shader. Some drivers will leave it untouched and simply work, others will do anything they want with it and you cannot make any assumptions about `gl_Layer` after `EmitVertex (...)`. *You are playing with fire, because it may not be the first vertex that defines a primitive's layer (more on this later).*

#### To fix this, re-write your geometry shader this way:

```
#version 400

layout(invocations = 32) in;
layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 raster_color;

float blue;

void main()
{
  blue = float(gl_InvocationID) / 31.0;

  gl_Position  = vec4( -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  raster_color = vec3( 0.0, 0.0, blue );
  gl_Layer = gl_InvocationID; // Handle case where First Vertex is Layer Provoking
  EmitVertex();

  gl_Position  = vec4( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  raster_color = vec3( 1.0, 0.0, blue );
  gl_Layer = gl_InvocationID; // Handle case where Layer Provoking vertex is Undefined
  EmitVertex();

  gl_Position  = vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  raster_color = vec3( 1.0, 1.0, blue );
  gl_Layer = gl_InvocationID; // Handle case where Last Vertex is Layer Provoking
  EmitVertex();

  EndPrimitive();
}
```

I would like to take this opportunity to point out that only 1 vertex in a primitive needs to have `gl_Layer` set; this vertex is called the Layer Provoking Vertex. Your shader assumes that the first vertex is the layer provoking vertex, but this is implementation-specific. When in doubt, the best solution is to cover all bases (set `gl_Layer` for all vertices).

You need to check `GL_LAYER_PROVOKING_VERTEX` at run-time to figure out which vertex defines your layer. If you do not want to do that, you can write your shader the way I described above. Provoking vertex conventions are usually first or last, but the way Geometry Shaders works leaves the possibility that any arbitrary vertex could define the layer (`GL_UNDEFINED_VERTEX`, and this is the case you should assume).

Comment: See [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Which_vertex) for more details on this situation. It applies to viewport provoking vertices as well.

Comment: I tried your code modifications to no avail, I'm afraid.

But then I kept searching elsewhere and found the source was something far more mundane. A syntax error in my texture parameters meant it wasn't clamping properly, and the top layer was wrapping back around to the bottom when sampled.

I understand per-vertex outputs far better now for future reference though. So thank you.

Comment: @Andy: Ah, gotcha. As I was writing this I had my doubts that it would fully explain your problem, but it needed to be addressed. Understanding this may save you a lot of frustration down the line ;) If you've figured out a solution, the best course of action would be to answer your own question. Even if it was something simple, add the code that was problematic and an explanation of your fix and mark it accepted. This is how Stack Overflow is supposed to work. A huge searchable Q&A database with verified solutions to problems.